# Which numerical method should I use that preserves solution's length?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, numerical-calculus

I am trying to solve an IVP problem consisting of the following equations:

> $y_1'=Ay_2$
> $y_2'=-Ay_1$
> $y_3'=0$

The analytical solution considering $y(0)=\left[\begin{matrix}Csin(\theta)\\
0\\
Ccos(\theta)
\end{matrix}\right]$ is :

> $y_1=Csin(\theta)cos(At)$
> $y_2=-Csin(\theta)sin(At)$
> $y_3=Ccos(\theta)$

Clearly the length(norm) of the analytical solution is constant for different $t$.
However, when I'm trying to approximate the solution using BDF or RK45 in Python the solution's length does not remain constant resulting to a lot of error as time grows.

How should I tackle this problem?

Comment: Look up Verlet integrator, Symplectic integrator

Comment: You missed a sign on $y_2'$, it should be $y_2'=-Ay_1$ not $y_2'=Ay_1$.  Use the Cayley transform for you propagation so you stay on the orthogonal group.

Comment: Using the correct rotation equation, also the standard solvers should give numerical solutions that preserve the length within the error tolerances. One might want to set these to some desired narrower values.

Comment: @user10354138 yes, I forgot adding the minus, thank you!

Comment: @LutzLehmann Actually when I used very small absolute and relative errors, the standard solvers worked!